# Как в bash к дате прибавить n дней? дата записана в виде переменной limit_date="2017-12-15"

Tags: bash

Как в bash к дате прибавить n дней? дата записана в виде переменной limit_date="2017-12-15"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```bsh
limit_date="2017-12-15"
n=30
limit_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$limit_date + $n days")
echo $limit_date # 2018-01-14
```

Comment: ответ хорош, но это не ответ на заданный вопрос. ведь программа date — это же не программа bash.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Как и абсолютное большинство других "команд" используемых в bash-скриптах. Это [unix way](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_Unix) - каждая программа выполняет свою маленькую задачу, результат достигается посредством взаимодействия программ.

Comment: по-моему, в ответе всё-таки стоит это отмечать. хотя бы минимальную «отмазку» типа «с помощью программы bash это, конечно, возможно, но решение будет очень громоздким. гораздо проще воспользоваться программой такой-то». я примерно так и делаю в подобных случаях.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ну тогда будем считать ваш комментарий таким предупреждением. Спасибо за отзыв.